# resolve the user's table error on Akeneo pim

Tags: php, symfony, akeneo

I installed Akeneo a pim (product interface manager based on Symfony and react) in my cluster. Everything is going as I want, except an error which prevents certain operations, especially product creation.

Everytime I select a view, I get this kind of error, something related to the database. The documentation is very bad, and I hope the someone has faced the same situation.

```
\"CREATE_TIME\" not available for table \"oro_user\"
```

Here is the whole error trace

```
[2021-05-27 14:36:55] request.INFO: Matched route "pim_analytics_data_collect". {"route":"pim_analytics_data_collect","route_parameters":{"_route":"pim_analytics_data_collect","_controller":"pim_analytics.controller.data:collectAction","_format":"json"},"request_uri":/analytics/collect_data","method":"GET"} []
[2021-05-27 14:36:55] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Akeneo\Platform\Bundle\InstallerBundle\Exception\UnavailableCreationTimeException: ""CREATE_TIME" not available for table "oro_user"" at /srv/pim/vendor/akeneo/pim-community-dev/src/Akeneo/Platform/Bundle/InstallerBundle/InstallStatusManager/InstallStatusManager.php line 67 {"exception":"[object] (Akeneo\\Platform\\Bundle\\InstallerBundle\\Exception\\UnavailableCreationTimeException(code: 0): \"CREATE_TIME\" not available for table \"oro_user\" at /srv/pim/vendor/akeneo/pim-community-dev/src/Akeneo/Platform/Bundle/InstallerBundle/InstallStatusManager/InstallStatusManager.php:67)"} []
[2021-05-27 14:36:55] request.INFO: Matched route "pim_analytics_data_collect". {"route":"pim_analytics_data_collect","route_parameters":{"_route":"pim_analytics_data_collect","_controller":"pim_analytics.controller.data:collectAction","_format":"json"},"request_uri":"/analytics/collect_data","method":"GET"} []
[2021-05-27 14:36:55] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Akeneo\Platform\Bundle\InstallerBundle\Exception\UnavailableCreationTimeException: ""CREATE_TIME" not available for table "oro_user"" at /srv/pim/vendor/akeneo/pim-community-dev/src/Akeneo/Platform/Bundle/InstallerBundle/InstallStatusManager/InstallStatusManager.php line 67 {"exception":"[object] (Akeneo\\Platform\\Bundle\\InstallerBundle\\Exception\\UnavailableCreationTimeException(code: 0): \"CREATE_TIME\" not available for table \"oro_user\" at /srv/pim/vendor/akeneo/pim-community-dev/src/Akeneo/Platform/Bundle/InstallerBundle/InstallStatusManager/InstallStatusManager.php:67)"} []
```

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention You MUST install MySQL and NOT MariaDb

That was the solution for me !